# ORA-00932 - inconsistent datatypes: expected LONG got CHAR

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle Version - 12.1.0.2

```
Table name: PERSON_DATA

PD_PERSON - FLOAT(126)
PD_REMARK - LONG
PD_DATE   - DATE
```

I have an issue with an SQL query called by application code. There query throws an error ORA-00932 - inconsistent datatypes: expected LONG got CHAR.

The query is as follows:

```
select nvl(PD_REMARK, '') from PERSON_DATA;
```

It has to be something to do with how Oracle is handling the '' string as if that is changed to `null` then it works without an issue. Also the strange thing is that this code worked until a few weeks ago when the Oracle database was switched over from the standby instance. This leads me to think there is some Oracle setting causing this but I just don't know what.

Comment: This seems to work on db<>fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f5a57a600eb57be810ccbf1579807376..

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Yes it works on my other databases. As I say it worked fine on the other instance before we switched over (ODG) to the current active instance.

Comment: In Oracle an empty string (`''`) is the same as a `NULL` value. Using `NVL( pd_remark, '' )` is the same as `NVL( pd_remark, NULL )` which is the same as `pd_remark` (and not using `NVL` at all).

Comment: @MT0 Thanks and I thought the same, however, if you change the statement to `select nvl(PD_REMARK, null) from PERSON_DATA;` then it works fine. There has to be some parameter or something which is affecting how the empty string is being used in Oracle.